# DJANGO: path searched will not match URL patterns

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I am new to Django following a tutorial, but cannot get past this error message from Django. I am typing in the file path exactly, but it will not work.

[image: Error Message]

Here is the website URLs .py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("hello/", include('testApp.urls')),
]
```

Here is the app's urls .py:

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)
]
```

Here is the app's view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def say_hello(request): 
    return HttpResponse("Bernz/Shell Boat Parts")
```

--Thank you.

I've tried http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello and http://127.0.0.1:8000/testAPP/hello and both have given me the same message that they do not match. Please help:

Answer (score 0):

You should visit `/hello/hello/`, the first one from the `path("hello/", include('testApp.urls')),` and the second from the `path('hello/', views.say_hello)`.

Likely however you want to remove the second one, so:

```
# testApp.urls

urlpatterns = [path('', views.say_hello)]
```

then it is `/hello/`

---

> **Note**: Django's apps normally are written in *snake_case*, so `test_app`, not <s>`testApp`</s>.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a close look of what you've done:

- In your project's urls.py, you've defined the following URL pattern:

```py
path("hello/", include('testApp.urls'))
```

This means that any URL that starts with "/hello/" should be handled by the testApp.urls file.

- In your app's urls.py, you've defined the following URL pattern:

```py
path('hello/', views.say_hello)
```

- This means that the URL "/hello/" should be handled by the say_hello view function.
  Together, the correct URL to access your page will be:
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/hello/

There is no reason to look at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/testAPP/hello
```

as you never defind an url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/testAPP/`. Instead, your testAPP is already pointed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/

To be able to access your App at http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello, you could change  the app's urls .py to:

```py
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.say_hello)  # Change this Line 
]
```

or the other way round, change project's urls.py to

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('testApp.urls')),  # Change this line
]
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked except, I had to do /hello/ <- including a slash after hello.